# sinusoidal frequency doubling

Tags: analog, frequency, signal-processing

In a project I'm working on, there is a need to supply satellite navigation receiver with signal from very precise external oscillator. Device, part of which receiver is, should be able to convert oscillator's 5 MHz sine wave to 10 MHz sine wave required by receiver.

What are the ways to do this conversion, without significantly reducing signal quality?

Looking for any guidance, as I know nothing about this kind of analog electronics.

Oscillator example: [link](http://www.vremya-ch.com/english/product/index28eb.html?Razdel=1&Id=33).

Comment: Frequency mixers maybe ?     http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/mixers/rf-mixers-mixing-basics-tutorial.php

Comment: I suggest you check with factory to see if they can give 10MHz output as it was mentioned on Osc link data sheet. I believe the factory can setup their system to output any frequency you desired (10MHz is popular, other are E1, T1, optical link ITU standards). I have the impression (but not 100% sure) that the output signal is internally PLL locked to the 1420 MHz of the hydrogen maser and different output frequency can be generated by changing the divide-by-n factor of the PLL sub-system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phase-locked loop built around a crystal TCVXO or ovenized oscillator with very narrow lock range might work for you. [Here's one](http://www.vectron.com/products/ocxo/ox-204.pdf) with good specs and a few hundred ppb tuning range.

I think that to not compromise the hydrogen maser oscillator phase noise is not going to be trivial, if that's what you need.

[image]

Comment: In old days, frequency doubler, a wireless telecommunication standard technique, especially in HF band, was feeding the signal to, says, a small class C amplifier, which generate multiple harmonic. Crystal filter is then used to extract second harmonic at 10MHz. 'Signal purity' is specified as dBc. Says, highest un-wanted signal is 60dB below the wanted 10MHz carrier. I have no idea how this specification can be converted to phase noise figure in dBc/Hz nor the 60dBc purity is good enough for this case. I recall some GPS time receiver has crystal filter  option for added phase noise reduction

Answer (score 1):

If the input is unmodulated, a [PLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLL) would be a sensible implementation.

1. Tunable oscillator generates 10 MHz sine
2. Comparator creates 10 MHz square wave
3. Digital frequency divider halves frequency
4. Signal is compared to input signal to generate control signal for the oscillator

It takes a few milliseconds for the PLL to start up, but if the input source is stable and your system isn't subjected to harsh temperature changes, it should remain stable and keep a fixed phase offset from the input frequency.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, you must use an RF mixer with a tuned circuit at the output.
The tuning frequency of this circuit is that of the desired signal.

Originally this was implemented with [class C amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Class_C), and an adjustable tuning tank circuit.

Perhaps there are today based on the processing of sampled signals, which allow you to generate the frequency (like the RF mixer) and then filtering.

The basic principle is "spread spectrum" by mixing two signals. It is the same principle that governs the amplitude modulation. This would allow you to obtain a sinusoidal frequency twice the original (or any other multiple), and even if the original signal conveys some information, this same information is reproduced at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is Frequency doubler. A push-push frequency doubler will generate even harmonics.

To select desired 10MHz signal, the output is tuned to two times the input frequency.

Multiple section LC filter can be used, then, follow by quartz crystal filter to get narrow pass band for low phase noise final output.

While this technique has been used successfully in real products, especially in old time HF transmitter, I am not sure if the phase noise can be filtered down to level as required of precision timing and master clock application.

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_transmitter_design#Frequency_multiplication